# angular table , cell with

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Is there a way we can extend the card which is on the cell up to the end of the table ? that there will be no padding , as you can see on the arrow on the screenshot, I wanted to extend the card up to end .

[image]

#html

```
  <mat-table class="-card" [dataSource]="table.dataSource" [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}" matMultiSort
        (matSortChange)="table.onSortEvent()" (contentChanged)="isLoadingTableData = false">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-multi-sort-header="status" >
                <span class="text-left">DATA</span>
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let model">
                <div class="card" style="width:100%;padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px !important;">
                    <div fxLayout="row">
                        DATA TEST
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="table.displayedColumns;" style="padding-bottom: 16px;">
        </mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let item; columns: table.displayedColumns;" style="cursor: pointer;">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

#css

```
.card{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* padding: 16px; */
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to set the padding zero to your `mat-cell` element something like

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let model"  class="p-0">
```

then in css

```
.p-0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gahbe3?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css)

Comment: Hi Sir, but the problem with the solution is that it removed the left and right border of radius of the card

https://imgur.com/a/LJUnEOf

Comment: how do we keep the border of the card?

Comment: you can try padding: 1px https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gahbe3?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css

Comment: Last question Sir, how do we remove the row border lines ? https://imgur.com/a/10aDSf0